# autoware runtime manager graphic bug

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the autoware runtime_manager for autoware 1.12.0 on ubuntu 18.04 with ROS melodic.

I installed autoware from source following these steps: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build (I build autoware without CUDA support)

To start the runtime_manager I use the following commands:

```
$ cd autoware.ai
$ source install/setup.bash
$ roslaunch runtime_manager runtime_manager.launch
```

As expected two terminals pop up, one running the roscore and one runing the runtime_manager. So far everything works as expected. But when I press any button in the runtime_manager (for example to start rviz) the runtime_manager starts to look like this:[image: image description]

There is no error visible in either of the running terminals.

Can someone please help me figure out how to solve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328986/autoware-runtime-manager-graphic-bug/) by [udeto](https://answers.ros.org/users/44010/udeto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://answers.ros.org/question/328788/gui-glitch-while-running-autoware/

We already have same question answered.

---

Originally posted by [mitsudome-r](https://answers.ros.org/users/41790/mitsudome-r/) with karma: 231 on 2019-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2